# How to detect when a specific key is pressed

Tags: c++, dos, turbo-c++

I am currently working on my school project in Turbo C++. I am sorry but it is necessary for my code to work on Turbo C++.
I plan on making a simple game, but with my beginner level knowledge, I cannot find a simple-to-understand method of detecting when and what arrow key is pressed.

In the game, I need to refresh my display regularly so I cannot use `getch()` to get the input as it will pause the game, but I don't know another way to get input without displaying it. So I thought to detect a key press and then use `getch()` but I don't know how to do that. Please help me figure out a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Please note that Turbo C++ is so old, many, if not all persons have to blow the dust off their Turbo C++ manuals to even help.  As to the arrow keys, you can try to research some old MSDOS articles on what key codes those arrow keys generate.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the subscribers here work with with C++ professionally, and use modern C++ compilers on modern operating systems. The chances that someone here is experienced with such an old, obsolete compiler that runs only on an operating system that's not actively used, for many decades, are somewhat slim. Your best chances of figuring out how to do this is to find some old technical MS-DOS books, and read them.

Comment: I know that it's old and outdated but that's the situation of Indian Schools. I am forced to make code that works on turbo c++. Sorry :(

Comment: As a note, this might be relevant to the Retrocomputing SE.  I'm not 100% certain that old compilers fit it, though, but it might be worth checking into.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for disturbing anyone with this unnecessary post.

I have luckily stumbled upon `kbhit()` (*which I didn't know existed*) in `conio.h` works like a charm. It detects key presses without stopping or interrupting the main code.

Thanks,